# Haskell: filter and sort using input values

Tags: list, sorting, haskell, input, filter

so I'm creating a program that will pick one of two libraries (audio.lhs or video.lhs) and will return a pdf with a list ordered and filtered by a given category:

```
mymain = do {putStrLn "What do you wanna search, Video or Audio?";  
          tipo <- getLine;   
          if tipo == "Audio"  
          then do {  
          a <- readFile "audio.lhs" ;  
          let text = splitEvery 7 (splitRegex (mkRegex "\t") a)  
              list = map musicFile text  
              select = filter ((>1000) .size) list  
              orderList = sortBy (comparing title)   
              dir = Dir orderList  
              hs =    "import Dir\nimport TeX\nimport System.Cmd"  
                   ++ "\ntoTeX= do { writeFile \"out.tex\" $ prettyprint dat ;"  
                   ++ "system \"pdflatex out\"}"  
                   ++ "\ndat="  
                   ++ show dir  
          in do { writeFile "dat.hs" hs ;  
                  putStrLn "\nOk.\nNow load \'dat.hs\' and run \'toTeX\'\n"  
                }}...
```

Everything is running but now i need that the functions

```
select = filter ((>1000) .size) list
```

and

```
orderList = sortBy (comparing title)
```

instead of working with values that are given by me, i want them to work with values choosen by the user of the program (inputs), so if he wants to filter files that are >2000 or <500 is his choice and same with the category,size or title or another thing.

My data structure is

```
data File = File {
 filename :: String ,
 size :: Int ,
 filetype :: String ,
 copyright :: String ,
 title :: String ,
 artist :: String ,
 year :: String } deriving Show
```

and

```
musicFile :: [String] -> File  
musicFile [name, size, tipo, copy, title, artist, year] = File name (read size) tipo copy title artist year
```

Any help would be gladly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're already making use of user input with `getLine`. How does that differ from what you want to do now? What have you tried?

Comment: i've tried using `getLine` but it wont understand when i give him an Integer, plus when i use a variable that will have a `getLine` value filter and compare fail because it's not what they are waiting for

Comment: It feels like we're doing pair programming here :-) You've asked four questions about this program over the last two days. I'm not sure Stack Overflow is the right place for that — maybe use the [Haskell IRC channel](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/IRC_channel) instead?

Comment: Yes i know, but if you see all the four questions were about the same problem

Comment: @seph: yes, they're basically discussions about the same program and personally, I feel a mailinglist or an IRC channel would be better suited.

Comment: Seriously mate, i'm not expecting anyone to right the code for me, i just need some lights to point me in the right direction. About the previous questions, with this one are 3 about this program, all three about the functions `orderList` and `select`, that at the beginning I didnt knew i had to work with inputs values, so i see this as rewriting the same previous 2 questions but in a different way. so if you are gonna be that helpful just dont bother to tip a comment.

Comment: As a side note, I am super-duper skeptical of this program's structure. Using Haskell to generate Haskell is a solution to a very specific problem, and from what I can see of the Haskell you're generating, you aren't running up against that kind of problem. Just write code; you don't need to write code that writes code.

Comment: ...and I just noticed that you're writing code (in Haskell, as a file) that writes code (in Haskell, as a String) that writes code (in TeX, as a String) that writes code (in PDF). A sane chain is just "Haskell -> PDF" (there are several libraries available for generating PDFs), or *maybe* if you need TeX's complicated layout algorithms, "Haskell -> TeX (as a TeX-specific data type) -> PDF" (there are libraries for generating well-formed TeX). This long chain of compilers with `String` as your only real data type is just... horrible.

Comment: This is the way i have to do it mate, believe or not the instructions i have is to make it this way.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest mechanism available in Haskell for parsing strings is the [`Read` typeclass](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#t%3aRead). Instances of this class have enough functionality to implement

```
read   :: (Read a) => String -> a
readLn :: (Read a) => IO a
```

either of which should be enough to get you started on your way to reading an `Int` (which is an instance of `Read`) from input.

Comment: hey Daniel, about reading an Integer i came out with    
    
`getInt :: IO Int`  
`getInt = readLn`  

the problem is in the ">" or "<"

Comment: @seph For a tutorial to using IO (and various other monads as well), choose one of sigfpe's excellent posts: [IO Monad for People Who Simply Don't Care](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2007/11/io-monad-for-people-who-simply-dont.html) or [You Could Have Invented Monads (And Maybe You Already Have)](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/you-could-have-invented-monads-and.html).